# libpd w/ Android Studio, unable to get the sound in

Tags: android, libpd

I migrated from Eclipse to AndroidStudio; 
I can get sounds from the project I've built with AndroidStudio/libpd but can not use mic to enter sound into Pd.

this is how I set audio parameters:

```
private void initPd() throws IOException {
AudioParameters.init(this);
        int srate = Math.max(44100, AudioParameters.suggestSampleRate());
        PdAudio.initAudio(srate, 1, 2, 8, true);
```

this is how I set the permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

this is the error I've got

```
AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -1
E/libOpenSLES﹕ android_audioRecorder_realize(0x62839188) error creating AudioRecord object
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, and although I know this question is old, it may help others searching for a solution.
With help from the contributors on the libpd github page, I found the cause(s) for receiving no input in my project...

Firstly, my targetsdkversion was API 23. As pointed out:
"Requesting permissions in API 23+ is something that needs to be done in the app itself, not in the pd-for-android library."
So I changed the target sdk version to 22.

Additionally, I had not added permission to my manifest to use the microphone. So adding this line to the Androidmanifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

Finally, I forgot to change the number of input channels from 0 when changing the source source from a osc~ to adc~. So my initPD method now looks like:

```
int sampleRate = AudioParameters.suggestSampleRate();
int inpch = AudioParameters.suggestInputChannels();
PdAudio.initAudio(sampleRate, inpch, 2, 8, true);
```

That did the trick for me..
Hopefully it helps you or someone else.